# How to check if a DataContext exists further up visual tree?

Tags: wpf, datacontext

I have a usercontrol (UC) that is sometimes in a window and sometimes in a tab and sometimes in a childwindow. When it's in a window I pass the window the viewmodel. In the UC I'd like to check if a datacontext already exists in an ancestor of the UC (not specifically the window because it has no knowledge if it's inside a window or a tab) so that I can instantiate a viewmodel is it's not. How can I check for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a DataContext is set for a visual ancestor, the UC inherits it, so you can just check if the DataContext of the UC is null.

Comment: Ah ok. Simple as that. Thanks

Comment: I took a little time to implement it and unfortunately it's not working. The DataContext of the UC that is added always returns null despite it's parent (the window) having it's DataContext set. I could be getting confused about the definition of a visual tree, but I'm simply creating the window, setting it's datacontext, adding the uc as the window's content then checking its datacontext.

Comment: @Steve, where do you check the DataContext of the UC? If you check in the constructor, the UC hasn't been added to the Window yet, so it can't have the DataContext of the parent...

Comment: yes, you're right, thanks Thomas. It would be nice if I could access it after InitializeComponent in the constructor, but it's not added yet.